# How to remove white space between paralax backgrond-image and a next div?

Tags: html, css

I was practising in css paralax and got a problem: between background image and a next div there is a white gap, you can just change the width of a viewport and scroll down to see it.

So, my  question is: Why it's happening and what I should do to remove it?

[A screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvcBS.png) and [Link on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jgfeg76/7/) or 
css code:

```
.car {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background: url(http://i63.tinypic.com/14viwxk.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: contain;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.car h1 {
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.car figure {
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 10%;
    color: white;
}

figure p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is simply too small. Change `background-size` to `cover` and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

What have say @Hunter it's correct, or you can change the `height: 600px;` to `height: 300px;` or use other pictures with height: 600px